# PlatformChecks.RequestPermissions is not available

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, zxing

I am using xamamrin for developing apps for android using c#, the IDE I am using is Visual studio.
I want to use zxing in my app, so I add zxing packet to both core and ui layers.

As you see in the below code, I can instantiate some classes, but I do not have any access to

```
 PlatformChecks.IsPermissionInManifest
```

I need it to check weather the required permissions are granted or not. Please have a look at the error message I am getting

Please let me know how to use it.

**error**

```
Error CS0103: The name 'PlatformChecks' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (MITScan.UI.Droid)
```

**code**:

```
 public static readonly string[] RequiredPermissions = new[] {
        Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
    };
    protected override async void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ZxingLibTestView);
        _scannerFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.tscan_4_view_relativelayout_cameraPreview, _scannerFragment, "Scannerfragment").Commit();

        var permissionsToRequest = new List<string>();

        // Check and request any permissions
        foreach (var permission in RequiredPermissions)
        {
            if (PlatformChecks.IsPermissionInManifest(this, 
  permission))
            {
                if (!PlatformChecks.IsPermissionGranted(this, 
  permission))
                    permissionsToRequest.Add(permission);
            }
        }

        if (permissionsToRequest.Any())
        {
            _waitingForPermission = 
  PlatformChecks.RequestPermissions(this, 
  permissionsToRequest.ToArray(), 101);
        } 

        }
```

**Note**:

```
I am using Zxing for scanning bar codes.
```

Comment: What are you using zxing for?

Comment: @G.hakim sorry that I did not mention that in my question. I am using it for scanning bar code.

Comment: And can you show me where you got this sample code from?

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the [Zebra Crossing's(ZXing)](https://github.com/jordanqin/ZXing.Scanner/tree/master/ZXing.Net.Mobile) docs after I read this question since I knew there is no such `Android` class and found that [PlatformChecks](https://github.com/jordanqin/ZXing.Scanner/blob/master/ZXing.Net.Mobile/Android/PlatformChecks.cs) is a Custom Class as below:

```
public class PlatformChecks
{
    public const string PERMISSION_CAMERA = "android.permission.CAMERA";
    public const string PERMISSION_FLASHLIGHT = "android.permission.FLASHLIGHT";

    public static bool HasCameraPermission(Context context)
    {
        return HasPermission (context, PERMISSION_CAMERA);
    }

    public static bool HasFlashlightPermission(Context context)
    {
        return HasPermission (context, PERMISSION_FLASHLIGHT);
    }

    static bool HasPermission(Context context, string permission)
    {
        PermissionInfo pi = null;

        try { pi = context.PackageManager.GetPermissionInfo (PERMISSION_CAMERA, PackageInfoFlags.Permissions); }
        catch { }

        return pi != null;
    }
}
```

And has the following using's

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content.PM;
```